# How to make panel-heading fixed with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have this Bootstrap structure:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" style="height:450px;overflow-y:auto">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">{% trans "News" %}</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body" style="padding:0;border:0px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

When I scroll the div `panel-heading` will not stay **fixed** as I want it to. How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just put **overflow-y** parametr in **panel-body** instead of in whole panel div:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">{% trans "News" %}</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body" style="padding:0;border:0px;height:450px;overflow-y:auto">
  </div>
</div>
```